# SQL : write a query to display employee records having same salary,same department but different city in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

Can someone explain how to find the query result, i am create the wuery but i dont get result

there are 2 tables in database

tblDepartment

```
Deptno  Dname
10     ACCOUNTING
20     RESEARCH
30     SALES
40     OPERATIONS
```

tblEmployee

```
Empno   Empname Job        Dept  Salary City
7698    Blake   Manager     10   5000   new york
7782    Clark   Manager     10   8000   Berlin
7566    Jones   Manager     20   7000   london
7654    Martin  Salesman    30   20000  new york
7499    Allen   Salesman    30   20000  tokyo
7844    Turner  Salesman    30   17000  new york
7900    James   Clerk       20   1000   delhi
7521    Ward    Salesman    10   15000  new york
```

in this table i am not getting the result as

> dept no 30 record

my SQL QUERY AS

```
select
    tblDepartment.Dname,
    tblEmployee.Empname,
    tblEmployee.Salary,
    tblEmployee.Empno
from
    tblDepartment
    left join tblEmployee
        on tblDepartment.Deptno = tblEmployee.Deptno 
where
    tblEmployee.Sal = tblEmployee.Sal
```

this Query return the same salary ,but i am not getting expected result,
Any body having any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count users with same salary and department and compare the result with count by salary, department and city. This query doesn't use self-joins.

```
SELECT 
     dat.Empno
FROM (
    SELECT 
         e.Empno
        ,e.Salary
        ,e.Dept
        ,e.City
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.Salary, e.Dept) AS CNT_salary_dept
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.Salary, e.Dept, e.City) AS CNT_salary_dept_city
    FROM tblEmployee e
) dat 
WHERE dat.CNT_salary_dept > dat.CNT_salary_dept_city
```

Answer (score 3):

`exists` comes to mind:

```
select e.*
from tblEmployee e
where exists (select 1
              from tblEmployee e2
              where e2.Deptno = e.Deptno and
                    e2.Salary = e.Salary and
                    e2.city <> e.city
             );
```

Comment: Wouldn't an `INNER JOIN` be more succint?

Comment: @Dai . . . It would produce unnecessary duplicates under some circumstances -- say when employees in more than two cities have the same department and salary.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there could be more than 2 employees having the same salary in the same department and with different cities, so you need 1 row per employee:

```
select 
  d.Dname,
  t.Salary,
  t.Empno,
  t.Empname, 
  t.City 
from tblEmployee t 
inner join tblDepartment d
on d.Deptno = t.Dept
where exists (
  select 1 from tblEmployee 
  where 
    Empno <> t.Empno and
    City <> t.City and
    Dept = t.Dept and
    Salary = t.Salary
)
order by d.Dname, t.Salary, t.Empname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E1.EmpNo AS FirstEmp 
       ,E2.EmpNo AS SecondEmp
       ,E1.Salary
       ,E1.Dept 
FROM tblEmployee E1 inner join
     tblEmployee E2 ON E2.Salary = E1.Salary
                       AND E2.Dept = E1.Dept
                       AND E1.City <> E2.City
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22049667)